# Block contact by NAME and not by number?

Tags: ios, contacts, spam

A while back I decided to save a robocaller to my contacts under the name "I is Scam". The interesting thing is I repeatedly get calls from the same exact contact, despite it showing up with different numbers located all across the nation. Every time I block one, it blocks that number only and I have to hit block for every single number despite all being named "I is Scam". **Not all** unknown numbers get linked to the contact, but many are.

How does the iPhone connect different, fake numbers to an existing contact? Finally, is there anyway to harness this technology to block the contact **name** and not the **number**?

Code answers welcome but simple answers preferred.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is possible, but if I was looking for a solution it would be one of the call blocking apps listed here https://medium.com/macoclock/12-best-call-blockers-for-iphone-ef1e913e7269 or here https://www.apppicker.com/applists/27779/the-best-call-blocking-apps-for-iphone There is no way to do this without 3rd party software, AFAIK. Your cell phone provider may also have an app, and it may be free. Wish I could offer more specific help.

Comment: That's a real shame. Number databases feel bloated and it seems like the iOS has the technology to detect the devise faking all these numbers. All the apps seem to be approaching the problem backwards imo

Comment: When I accidentally "called back" to one of these missed forged caller ID scams, the phone dialed a different number.  That suggests to me that the cell provider has the ability to detect and block forged caller ID.  And should do so.

Comment: See if your country has the equivalent of the UK's [Telephone Preference Service](https://www.tpsonline.org.uk) Your phone provider will also probably have its own service for spam texts. Usually accessible by forwarding the text to 'spam'  UK number is 7726 … which spells spam on an alphanumeric dialler ;)